# C++ dynamic_cast a template class to another template

Tags: c++

I am working with template class `A<widget_type>` and I want to know if it is possible to `dynamic_cast<A<another_type>*>(A<widget_type>*)`.
Question: in the following code, `A<B>* target2 = dynamic_cast<A<B>*>(&source);` returns a null pointer. Is it possible to cast a template class into the same class but with another template?
Edit: I have to make a program where an array holds `A<B*>` objects, but `A<B*>` objects may come from `A<C*>` or `A<D*>`. I need to check at run-time if the `A<B*>` can be casted into the desired template class. I can't use strong-typing for that reason, since `A<B*>` object may come from an `A<E*>` object, where `E` is a class that other people may create and thus, there may not be a conversion function into that template class.
Code:

````
template<typename widget_type>
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<widget_type*> value;

    virtual ~A() {}

    void Add(widget_type* val)
    {
        value.push_back(val);
    }
    template<typename return_type>
    operator A<return_type>()
    {
        unsigned int size = this->value.size();
        std::vector<return_type*> return_value;
        return_value.resize(size);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            return_value[i] = dynamic_cast<return_type*>(this->value[i]);
        }
        A<return_type> target;
        target.value = return_value;
        return target;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "C CALL\n";
    }
};

class D : public B
{

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start!\n";
    A<C> source;
    C* val1 = new C;
    source.Add(val1);
    A<B> target = source;
    A<B>* target2 = dynamic_cast<A<B>*>(&source);
    if (target2)
    {
        std::cout << "POINTER\n"; 
    }
    std::cout << "END\n";
}```
````

Comment: Some sort of `template_cast`? Not directly, but you could write a conversion function I guess.

Comment: Even the dynamic cast in the templated output member function is questionable. Better to implement proper conversion functions. Strong typing is there for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dynamic_cast will only succeed if there is some kind of inheritance relation between where you are coming from and where you are going to.

If you simply want to treat a pointer of one type as a pointer to a different type (which in general is true of different specializations of the same template) then dynamic_cast will not succeed. Only a c-style or reinterpret_cast will allow the cast but even then the results are not defined.

Comment: C-style cast always returns something? I want to check if ```A<widget_type*>``` can be casted safely into another template. As far as I know, with ```A<C*>```, changing it with C-style into ```A<D*>``` would produce a weird result, whereas my further goal is to check if it can be casted without any error